# Selection Sort giving the incorrect output

Tags: java, selection-sort

I'm having a problem for my output in this Selection Sort.

Here's the code:

```
public class SelectionSort{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int [] arr_sort = {1, 7, 2, 18, 23, 13};

        System.out.println("Selection Sort");
        System.out.print("Before sorting: ");
        int x;
        for(x=0; x<arr_sort.length; x++){
            System.out.print(arr_sort[x] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("After sorting: ");

        int n = arr_sort.length;
        int i,j, min, temp;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            min=1;
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
         if (arr_sort[j]<arr_sort[min]){
            min=j;
            temp=arr_sort[i];
            arr_sort[i]=arr_sort[min];
            arr_sort[min]=temp;
        }

    }

System.out.print(arr_sort[i] + " ");
 }

}

}
```

Output:

```
Selection Sort
Before sorting: 1 7 2 18 23 13 
After sorting: 2 1 7 18 23 13
```

Comment: So...what's the problem?  I must have missed that part in reading your question.

Comment: The sorting is kinda messed up as you can see in the "After sorting"
It should be: 1, 2, 7, 13, 18, 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `min` is declared outside the loop is the problem.

When starting a new iteration, it will still retain the old value, so you'll be comparing with an element already found to be the minimum and selected.

Also, `min` shouldn't be `1`, make it `i` instead, as you don't want to be comparing with the second element at each step.

After these changes it works, but it's not really selection sort, you need to find the minimum and only swap then, not each time you find a smaller element.

On to the code:

```
int n = arr_sort.length;
int i, j, temp; // min removed here
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  int min = i; // min declared here and changed to i
  for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
  {
     if (arr_sort[j] < arr_sort[min])
     {
        min = j;
     }
  }
  // moved swap to here
  temp = arr_sort[i];
  arr_sort[i] = arr_sort[min];
  arr_sort[min] = temp;
  System.out.print(arr_sort[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to find what causes this code's problem.
You helped me a lot, many thanks!